# Django reverse() and CBV

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I know I'm doing something stupid here, but I can't seem to find it (must be teh stupid).

In urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns=patterns(...
    ...
    url(r'(?P<cat>[-\w]*)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', PlantDetailView.as_view(), name='detail-view'),
    ....
    )
```

And in the template I have:

```
{%  url 'detail-view' cat=category_slug slug=plant.slug %}
```

But I get the following NoReverseMatch error:

`Reverse for 'detail-view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'foo', u'cat': u'bar'}' not found.`

I've tried using `*args` and `**kwargs`, but no luck.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: django's new syntax doesn't have `'` around your view name in templates (`{%  url detail-view cat=category_slug slug=plant.slug %}`)

Comment: ps: don't use `*` as it means 0 or more. in your case, that will yield a `//this-is-slug` type of url, which is wrong. use `+` instead

Comment: I had tried the syntax without the single quotes already and it doesn't work: `Could not parse the remainder: '-view' from 'detail-view'. The syntax of 'url' changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.`

Comment: Also, there is a reason I'm using `*` in the RE. We could talk about it later.

Comment: So I tried re-naming to detail_view, as the `-` seemed to be a problem in the template. But still no love: `'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.`

Comment: Daaaamn I always get confused with old and new url syntax. Sorry for misleading first comment :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a namespace issue.

Since the 'plants' urls are included in the main urls.py, the solution is:

```
{%  url 'plants:detail_view' cat=category_slug slug=plant.slug %}
```

I'm sure that Samuele Mattiuzzo would have caught it had I said that the url file was `plants/urls.py` but I left out that important detail.

Thanks for your help, anyway.